# Filling a dataframe column after checking multiple conditions based on other columns from the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I need to fill up a column with some values based on multiple conditions from multiple other columns

This is my current [DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSiPt.png), and these are the conditions I will need to check for each row. [Conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyKFj.png)

I need to create a new column that will be filled with either of the values from this - [list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WdSq.png) based on the conditions mentioned above for each row one by one.

I am currently exploring the idea of using np.where but how do I use it for each row and check all 6 conditions together?

Comment: Post your actual code, not images.

Comment: its tough to post the actual code as I am looking for a direction to achieve my logic

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To check all conditions together you can use this:

```
df_filterd = df.loc[ (df['column1'] < condition1) & (df['column2'] < condition2 &...]
```

Comment: I saw that method but its more like a switch case situation that we can implement in C where the value of df_filtered will be determined based on 6 cases and each case has a condition

Comment: So Df_filtered will be 1 lets say if column1 is greater than column 2 & column 3 is < column 1. But df_filtered can also 2,3,4,5,6